# Validation ng-form Angular not working

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I make a form using ng-form and want to disable the button if input field is invalid, I have tried but it still doesn't work. I don't what I'm missing.

This is the code

```
 <button 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        ng-click="compose('Submit',1)"
        ng-disabled="memo.nestedForm.perihal.$invalid">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o">&nbsp;</i> 
        Kirim
    </button>
<form class="tab-form-demo" ng-controller="userCtrl" role="form" name="memo" novalidate>
    <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Informasi Surat">
        <ng-form name="nestedForm" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">Perihal</label>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="surat.subject" name="perihal" required>
                <div ng-show='nestedForm.perihal.$dirty && nestedForm.perihal.$invalid'>
                    <span ng-show='nestedForm.perihal.$error.required'>Required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </ng-form>
      </uib-tab>

    </uib-tabset>
  </form>
```

Comment: why do you want to use ng-from ?? you could just use normal from ???

Comment: move the button inside form, then it may work

Comment: @BOSS, Actually I have many input fields so I have to use ng-form.

Comment: @Sravan, It still doesn't work. I think it's okay if I put the button outside form as long as I access the form's name and ng-form's name.

Comment: @JarachanthanRatnakumar I made it in plunkr here the link https://plnkr.co/edit/Viu11dSCNRUU7rbFkxBd?p=preview but in plunkr it works, why in my editor it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **move the button inside the form** to `validate`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body>

<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>

<p>Email:<br>
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
</span>
</p>

<button 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        ng-click="compose('Submit',1)"
        ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o">&nbsp;</i> 
        Kirim
    </button>


</form>

<button 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        ng-click="compose('Submit',1)"
        ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o">&nbsp;</i> 
        Kirim outside form
    </button>




<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'Test';
    $scope.email = 'Test@gmail.com';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above code, and check the two buttons**

[HERE is the Working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pPDLMTkTQ6NpJkg3lmeA?p=preview)

Comment: @Diini Salma, please check the example link that I posted.

Comment: Remove the username and then you can see one button getting disabled which is inside form. the button that is outside will not get disabled.

Comment: Ya, I try to put the button inside the form and it works. Thank you. But I still confuse why while I try my code in plunkr it works, but in my editor doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try  inserting  the button inside  from tag .

```
<form class="tab-form-demo" ng-controller="userCtrl" role="form" name="memo" novalidate>
    <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Informasi Surat">
        <ng-form name="nestedForm" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">Perihal</label>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="surat.subject" name="perihal" required>
                <div ng-show='nestedForm.perihal.$dirty && nestedForm.perihal.$invalid'>
                    <span ng-show='nestedForm.perihal.$error.required'>Required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </ng-form>
      </uib-tab>

    </uib-tabset>

       <button 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        ng-click="compose('Submit',1)"
        ng-disabled="memo.nestedForm.perihal.$invalid">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o">&nbsp;</i> 
        Kirim
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: this answer is same as my comment and answer.

Comment: Maybe, you wanna check my code here https://plnkr.co/edit/Viu11dSCNRUU7rbFkxBd?p=preview . In here my code works but in my editor it doesn't.

Comment: this could mean you have other problems  in your code @DiiniSalma